# Testing my Flask application with pytests gives status code 422 ('Missing data for required field.') even though data is passed

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jwt, pytest

So I have this flask application and I'm trying to test it with pytest
app.py:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_smorest import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from db import db
from resources.item import blp as ItemBlueprint
from resources.store import blp as StoreBlueprint
from resources.tag import blp as TagBlueprint
from resources.user import blp as UserBlueprint
from blocklist import BLOCKLIST


def create_app(db_url=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config["PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS"] = True
    app.config["API_TITLE"] = "Stores REST API"
    app.config["API_VERSION"] = "v1"
    app.config["OPENAPI_VERSION"] = "3.0.3"
    app.config["OPENAPI_URL_PREFIX"] = "/"
    app.config["OPENAPI_SWAGGER_UI_PATH"] = "/swagger-ui"
    app.config["OPENAPI_SWAGGER_UI_URL"] = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist/"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = db_url or os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///data.db")
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True

    db.init_app(app)
    api = Api(app)

    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = '69490938337699758397870296439802775085'
    jwt = JWTManager(app)

    @jwt.needs_fresh_token_loader
    def token_not_fresh_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return (
            jsonify(
                {
                    "description": "The token is not fresh.",
                    "error": "fresh_token_required",
                }
            ),
            401,
        )

    @jwt.token_in_blocklist_loader
    def check_if_token_in_blocklist(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return jwt_payload['jti'] in BLOCKLIST

    @jwt.revoked_token_loader
    def revoked_token_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return (
            jsonify(
                {
                    "description": "The token has been revoked.",
                    "error": "token_revoked"
                }
            )
        )

    @jwt.additional_claims_loader
    def add_claims_to_jwt(identity):
        if identity == 1:
            return {"is_admin": True}
        return {"is_admin": False}

    @jwt.expired_token_loader
    def expired_token_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return (
            jsonify(
                {
                    "message": "The token has expired.",
                    "error": "token_expired"
                }
            ),
            401,
        )

    @jwt.invalid_token_loader
    def invalid_token_callback(error):
        return (
            jsonify(
                {
                    "message": "Signature verification failed.",
                    "error": "invalid_token"
                }
            ), 401,
        )

    @jwt.unauthorized_loader
    def missing_token_callback(error):
        return (
            jsonify(
                {
                    "description": "Request does not contain an access token.",
                    "error": "authorization_required",
                }
            ), 401,
        )

    # @app.before_first_request
    # def create_tables():
    #     db.create_all()

    api.register_blueprint(ItemBlueprint)
    api.register_blueprint(StoreBlueprint)
    api.register_blueprint(TagBlueprint)
    api.register_blueprint(UserBlueprint)
    return app
```

And I am trying to test some endpoints like create a store, so I'm doing this in the tests/conftest.py

```
from app import create_app

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client():
    flask_app = create_app()
    flask_app.testing = True

    flask_app.testing = True
    with flask_app.test_client() as testing_client:
        with flask_app.app_context():
            yield testing_client
```

And there is the test for creation of a store

```
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token


def test_store_creation(client):
    """
    GIVEN a Store model
    WHEN a new Store is created
    THEN check the name field is defined correctly
    """
    access_token = create_access_token('admin')
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
    }
    response = client.post('/store', data={"name": "test_store"}, headers=headers)

    print(response.get_json())
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

The Store schema

```
class PlainItemSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    price = fields.Float(required=True)

class PlainTagSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str()

class PlainStoreSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str(required=True)

class StoreSchema(PlainStoreSchema):
    items = fields.List(fields.Nested(PlainItemSchema()), dump_only=True)
    tags = fields.List(fields.Nested(PlainTagSchema()), dump_only=True)
```

My Store Blueprint

```
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask_smorest import abort, Blueprint
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError, IntegrityError
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, get_jwt

from schemas import StoreSchema
from db import db
from models import StoreModel


blp = Blueprint('stores', __name__, description='Operations on stores')


@blp.route('/store/<int:store_id>')
class Store(MethodView):
    @blp.response(200, StoreSchema)
    def get(self, store_id):
        store = StoreModel.query.get_or_404(store_id)
        return store

    @jwt_required(fresh=True)
    def delete(self, store_id):
        """Only admins can delete stores"""
        jwt = get_jwt()
        if not jwt.get('is_admin'):
            abort(400, message='Admin privilege required.')

        store = StoreModel.query.get_or_404(store_id)
        db.session.delete(store)
        db.session.commit()
        return {"message": "Store deleted"}

@blp.route("/store")
class StoreList(MethodView):
    @blp.response(200, StoreSchema(many=True))
    def get(self):
        return StoreModel.query.all()

    @jwt_required()
    @blp.arguments(StoreSchema)
    @blp.response(201, StoreSchema)
    def post(self, store_data):
        store = StoreModel(**store_data)
        try:
            db.session.add(store)
            db.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            abort(
                400,
                message="A store with that name already exists.",
            )
        except SQLAlchemyError:
            abort(500, message="An error occurred creating the store.")

        return store
```

The error I'm getting is this

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_stores.py::test_store_creation FAILED                               [100%]{'code': 422, 'errors': {'json': {'name': ['Missing data for required field.']}}, 'status': 'Unprocessable Entity'}

test_stores.py:4 (test_store_creation)
422 != 201

Expected :201
Actual   :422
<Click to see difference>

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'app'>>

    def test_store_creation(client):
        """
        GIVEN a Store model
        WHEN a new Store is created
        THEN check the name field is defined correctly
        """
        data = {
            "name": "test"
        }
    
        access_token = create_access_token('admin')
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
        }
        response = client.post('/store', headers=headers, data=data)
    
        print(response.get_json())
>       assert response.status_code == 201
E       assert 422 == 201
E        +  where 422 = <WrapperTestResponse 109 bytes [422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY]>.status_code

test_stores.py:22: AssertionError
```

**It's like I'm not sending any data in the *cliet.post()* method, In fact if I remove the '*data={'name': 'test'}*' I get the same result.**
I tried to put data dict outside the method and convert it to json with json.dumps(data) still getting the result

Comment: Can you post "/store" endpoint function from your blueprint?

Comment: just posted it above the exception

Comment: You also need to provide `StoreSchema` and full traceback of your error.

Comment: Okay, I've put them as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask-smorest` is expecting you to post `json` data as default, so automatically send it as `json` OR adjust your header manually to reflect the data your are sending.

Fix your code as:

```py
response = client.post("/store", json={"name": "test_store"}, headers=headers)
```